# Getting error 'numpy.float64' object not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, machine-learning

While executing recommend() function i am getting error at line

```
movies_list = sorted([enumerate(distances[0])], reverse=True, key = lambda x:x[1])[1:6]
```

The following is the code I tried. please suggest changes in it:

```
def recommend1(movie):
  movie_index = new_df[new_df['title']== movie].index[0]
  distances = similarity[movie_index]
  movies_list = sorted([enumerate(distances[0])], reverse=True , key = lambda x:x[1])[1:6]

for i in movies_list :
 print(new_df.iloc[i[0]].title)
```

Output after executing following statement:
recommend1('Avatar')

Error I got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-76a841473d9d> in <module>
----> 1 recommend1('Avatar')

<ipython-input-61-27f7c47f4ecd> in recommend1(movie)
    2   movie_index = new_df[new_df['title']== movie].index[0]
    3   distances = similarity[movie_index]
----> 4   movies_list = sorted([enumerate(distances[0])], reverse=True , key = lambda x:x[1])[1:6]
    5 
    6   for i in movies_list :

    TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`
```

Comment: Remove the `[]` from around `enumerate(....)`.  As the code is no written, you're sorting a list with a single element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.